# Chrome hangs when using javascript to check many checkboxes, while firefox does it instantly

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery

I'm using an asp:Repeater server side control that contains a table as it's repeatable item.  One of the td tags in the table contains a checkbox.  In the header of the repeater I have a checkbox with id="selectAllCheck".

I have the following javascript code

```
    var checkBox = document.getElementById('selectAllCheck');

    function changeAll() {
        if (checkBox.checked == 1) {
            $('input:checkbox').attr('checked', "checked");
        }
        else {
            $('input:checkbox').attr('checked', "");
        }
    }

    checkBox.onchange = changeAll;
```

This works just fine in firefox, instantly all the checkboxes are either checked or unchecked when necessary.  However, in chrome it takes about 10 seconds.  I do have about 250 checkboxes on the page by the way, but even putting that number down to only 15, I can see that it is still not instant with chrome, but much faster.

If anyone has encountered this problem before, seen any articles related to this problem, or knows how to solve this problem I would be very thankful.

EDIT: Posted the page

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentMain" Runat="Server">
<form id="webForm" runat="server">
    <asp:Label ID="sourceLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="sourceList" Text="Source"></asp:Label>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="sourceList" runat="server" />&nbsp;
    <asp:Button ID="showButton" runat="server" Text="View" />
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater_DIBS" runat="server">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <table>
            <tr><th><input type="checkbox" id="selectAllCheck" /> (un)check All</th>    <th>SourceID</th><th>FieldID</th><th>Source Indicator</th><th>Date Data Updated</th>   <th>Message</th></tr>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td style='width:1%;white-space:nowrap;'><input type='checkbox' class='checkBoxes' /></td>
                <td style='width:1%;white-space:nowrap;'><%# Eval("SourceID") %></td>
                <td style='width:1%;white-space:nowrap;'><%# Eval("FieldID") %></td>
                <td class='indicator' style='width:1%;white-space:nowrap;'><%# Eval("SourceIndicator") %></td>
                <td style='width:1%;white-space:nowrap;'><%# Eval("DateDataUpdated") %></td>
                <td style='width:1%;white-space:nowrap;' class='status'></td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>

        <FooterTemplate>
            </table>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</form>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentJS" Runat="Server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#selectAllCheck").change(function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            $("input:checkbox.checkBoxes").attr("checked", "checked");
        }
        else {
            $("input:checkbox.checkBoxes").removeAttr("checked");
        }
    });

</script>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's a bug in Chrome. The more checkboxes you have on a page, the slower the process gets. When you have around 500, the speed is ok. The problem is that when you get over 1000, the process to check all the boxes exponentially gets larger. In IE9 and FF4, this process does not matter. Even if you did not use jQuery and try to use straight js, you end up with Chrome getting slower the more checkboxes you use on a page.

Try limiting the number of checkboxes if possible.

Comment: Two years later it seems like this is still the case, a page with 500+ checkboxes is excruciatingly slow in Chrome while a similar page in Firefox runs quite fast.

Answer (score 2):

You are selecting all the checkboxes in the page. Instead of this assign a class to all the child checkboxes and toggle the checked property of those textboxes. Also specify a parent element so that the search will be more specific. Something like

```
$("#chkAll").change(function(){
    if (this.checked) {
        $("#containerid input:checkbox.yourclass").attr("checked", "checked");
    }
    else {
        $("#containerid input:checkbox.yourclass").removeAttr("checked");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this refactoring and it should speed things up:

```
$(function() {
    $("#selectAllCheck").click(function(){
        $("input:checkbox:not(#selectAllCheck)").attr("checked", $(this).is(":checked"));
    });
});
```

binds the event to `#selectAllCheck` and checks all remaining checkboxes.

---

example here: http://jsfiddle.net/mDGzW/1/

works instant in Chrome....

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but using that code instead produces the exact same time delay.

Comment: can you show some HTML? This might be more of an IA and UI issue than a jQuery issue. There's a good chance you should not be showing 250 checkboxes, but there's always an exception to the rule

Comment: I'm not sure why it is working for you and not for me.  Other than the fact that I'm using a Repeater.  Maybe that is the issue?

Comment: The repeater shouldn't matter. Can you test your code in Safari? Do you use any Chrome plug-ins?

Comment: I have no Chrome plug-ins installed.  It takes longer than I like in Safari, but it's reasonable.

Comment: try removing all of those inline `td` styles

Comment: even this example based on your repeater runs pretty quickly: http://jsfiddle.net/mDGzW/2/

Comment: I removed all the inline td styles.  It still isn't running very quickly.  Thanks for all your suggestions though.  It must be something I'm overlooking.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a attr / removeAttr:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#selectAllCheck').click(function(){
            if($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $('input:checkbox').attr('checked', 'checked');
            }
            else {
            $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
            }
     });
});
```

Comment: Maybe your delay is due to another piece of code in your page. Could you provide a copy of the page?

Comment: Very good... but can you add the html output from your ASP.Net page?

Comment: Fixed a mistake in my code... i didn't use $(this) for the check... fixed it in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Do not look up all of the checkboxes all of the time. If they are not dynamic, there is no reason to do it.  It takes the browser a good amount of time to always look through the DOM to find the elements. Do it once and keep the reference.

Also the best selector you can use is just a classname in this case. The "input:checkbox" look up is a lot slower than just looking at the class.

[Basic idea:](http://jsbin.com/owima4/2/edit)

```
  (function(){

    var cbs = $(".cb");

    $("#checkall").click(
      function(){
         var state = this.checked;
         cbs.attr("checked", state);
      }
    )

  })();
```

Comment: I really thought that was going to work.  But it still takes too long.

Answer (score 1):

A few minor performance tweaks:

http://jsfiddle.net/H9kK9/2/

- Cache your list of checkboxes upfront, so the expensive DOM query is already finished when a user triggers onChange
- Use the native "checked = true/false" instead of jQuery's prop/attr wrapper, to save on overhead. Checked is a very stable, old DOM property, and you should feel comfortable setting it on a DOM element without jQuery's help.